# why the name of the data in the directive give error?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this in html file:

```
<prevalence ng-if="model.mode == 'Prevalence'" data="prevalenceData" colors="colors" maxL="maxL"></prevalence>
```

and in the directive maxL undefined. if I change L to l => maxL to maxl it's defined.
what could be the reason? I test it on some variation and get that it's the uppercase letter that give me the problem.

in the directive js file there is:

```
angular.module('x').directive('prevalence', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            colors: '=',
            maxL: '='
        },
```

thanks!

Comment: Angular rename all Camel Case string to underscore try max_l

Comment: Dashes, not underscores…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `maxL` attribute in the HTML to `max-l`, like so:

```
<prevalence ng-if="model.mode == 'Prevalence'" data="prevalenceData" colors="colors" max-l="maxL"></prevalence>
```

HTML is case-insensitive, so the angular compiler assumes the `camelCase` attribute in your directive is actual `camel-case`dashed in your HTML.